# MySQL : trigger to capitalize first letter of each word

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

So here it is guys,

**I have a table containing this** :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `people` (
`Id_People` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Firstname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`Lastname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id_People`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1002 ;
```

How can I set a trigger that will capitalize the first letter of my Firstname and Lastname?

---

Whenever I add someone,

**On the insert** :

```
INSERT INTO people (Firstname, Lastname) VALUES ('doe', 'john')
```

---

Whenever I edit someone,

**And on the update** :

```
UPDATE people SET Lastname = 'smith', Firstname= 'jane' WHERE Id_People = 1;
```

---

And this even with a double-barrelled name such as : john smith (firstname) doe (lastname)?

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It's done, thanks for your review.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can suggest that you are using MySql RDBMS.

MySql doesnt provide standart function for capitalize first letter in each word.

Firstly,

Create this function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `capitalize`(s varchar(255)) RETURNS varchar(255) 
BEGIN
  declare c int;
  declare x varchar(255);
  declare y varchar(255);
  declare z varchar(255);

  set x = UPPER( SUBSTRING( s, 1, 1));
  set y = SUBSTR( s, 2);
  set c = instr( y, ' ');

  while c > 0
    do
      set z = SUBSTR( y, 1, c);
      set x = CONCAT( x, z);
      set z = UPPER( SUBSTR( y, c+1, 1));
      set x = CONCAT( x, z);
      set y = SUBSTR( y, c+2);
      set c = INSTR( y, ' ');     
  end while;
  set x = CONCAT(x, y);
  return x;
END$$
```

Secondly,

Create triggers for update and insert

```
CREATE TRIGGER frst_l_up_insert BEFORE INSERT ON people FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.Firstname = capitalize(NEW.Firstname), NEW.Lastname = capitalize(NEW.Lastname);

CREATE TRIGGER frst_l_up_update BEFORE UPDATE ON people FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.Firstname = capitalize(NEW.Firstname), NEW.Lastname = capitalize(NEW.Lastname)
```

Finally,

Update existings record in the table

```
UPDATE people SET Lastname = capitalize(Lastname), Firstname = capitalize(Firstname);
```